# *wpupdateuser* user_login in my WordPress database

Tags: users

Recently, I've started to notice a **wpupdateuser** user_login in my WordPress databases.  Is this correct, or a compromise?

Comment: That does seem a bit strange. What role does it have?

Comment: Just checked on this.  Role is 'administrator'.  I definitely didn't set this user up, so I'm chalking it up to a compromise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**wpupdateuser** does not appear correct.  Is it a compromise?  Possibly not if you are allowing user registrations.  A Google search for wpupdateuser reveals numerous sites where this username appears.  Make sure WP and plugins are up to date.

Comment: Yep, I saw the same thing.  Tells me that it's a known issue and other sites are affected.  I'm putting together a bash script now that should be able to check through the databases and find any instances, but the table prefix varies, so I'll need to figure out how to get around that.